# Parsing a string with multi-char delimiter and got junk data along with the result in the second call in c

Tags: c, string, split, malloc, buffer

I have writen a code to split the string with multiple char delimiter.

It is working fine for first time of calling to this function

but i calling it second time it retuns the correct word with some unwanted symbol.

I think this problem occurs because of not clearing the buffer.I have tried a lot but cant solve this. please help me to solve this problem.

```
char **split(char *phrase, char *delimiter) {
    int i = 0;
    char **arraylist= malloc(10 *sizeof(char *));
    char *loc1=NULL;
    char *loc=NULL;
    loc1 = phrase;
    while (loc1 != NULL) {
    loc = strstr(loc1, delimiter);
    if (loc == NULL) {
            arraylist[i]=malloc(sizeof(loc1));
            arraylist[i]=loc1;
            break;
    }
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);    // memory for 256 char
    int length = strlen(delimiter);
    strncpy(buf, loc1, loc-loc1);
    arraylist[i]=malloc(sizeof(buf));
    arraylist[i]=buf;
    i++;
    loc = loc+length;
    loc1 = loc;
}
return arraylist;
}
```

called this function first time

```
char **splitdetails = split("100000000<delimit>0<delimit>hellooo" , "<delimit>");
```

It gives

```
splitdetails[0]=100000000
splitdetails[1]=0
splitdetails[2]=hellooo
```

but i called this second time

```
char **splitdetails = split("20000000<delimit>10<delimit>testing" , "<delimit>");

splitdetails[0]=20000000��������������������������
splitdetails[1]=10����
splitdetails[2]=testing
```

Update:-

thanks to @fatelerror. i have change my code as

```
    char** split(char *phrase, char *delimiter) {
    int i = 0;
    char **arraylist = malloc(10 *sizeof(char *));
    char *loc1=NULL;
    char *loc=NULL;
    loc1 = phrase;
    while (loc1 != NULL) {
    loc = strstr(loc1, delimiter);
    if (loc == NULL) {
            arraylist[i]=malloc(strlen(loc1) + 1);
            strcpy(arraylist[i], loc1);
            break;
    }
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);    // memory for 256 char
    int length = strlen(delimiter);
    strncpy(buf, loc1, loc-loc1);
    buf[loc - loc1] = '\0';
    arraylist[i]=malloc(strlen(buf));
    strcpy(arraylist[i], buf);
    i++;
    loc = loc+length;
    loc1 = loc;
   }
}
```

In the caller function, i used it as

```
char *id
char **splitdetails = split("20000000<delimit>10<delimit>testing" , "<delimit>");
id = splitdetails[0];
//some works done with id
//free the split details with this code.
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    free(domaindetails[i]);
}free(domaindetails);
domaindetails=NULL;
```

then i called the same for the second as,

```
char **splitdetails1= split("10000000<delimit>1000<delimit>testing1" , "<delimit>");
```

it makes error and i can't free the function.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem boils down to three basic things:

1. `sizeof` is not `strlen()`
2. Assignment doesn't copy strings in C.
3. `strncpy()` doesn't always nul-terminate strings.

So, when you say something like:

```
arraylist[i]=malloc(sizeof(loc1));
arraylist[i]=loc1;
```

thisdoes not copy the string. The first one allocates the size of `loc1`, which is a `char *`. In other words, you allocated the size of a pointer. You want to allocate storage to store the string, i.e. using `strlen()`:

```
arraylist[i]=malloc(strlen(loc1) + 1);
```

Note the `+ 1` as well, because you also need room for the nul-terminator. Then, to copy the string you want to use `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy(arraylist[i], loc1);
```

The way you had it was just assigning a pointer to your old string (and in the process leaing the memory you had just allocated). It's also common to use `strdup()` which combines both of these steps, i.e.

```
arraylist[i] = strdup(loc1);
```

This is convenient but `strdup()` is not part of the official C library. You need to assess the portability needs of your code before you consider using it.

**Additionally, with `strncpy()`, you should be aware that it does *not* always nul-terminate:**

```
strncpy(buf, loc1, loc-loc1);
```

This copies less bytes than were in the original string and doesn't terminate `buf`. Thus, it's necessary to include a nul terminator yourself:

```
buf[loc - loc1] = '\0';
```

**This is the root cause** of what you are seeing with the garbage. Since you didn't nul terminate, C doesn't know where your string ends and so it keeps on reading whatever happens to be in memory.

Comment: strdup is part of the POSIX standard; you can expect it to be available whereever people care about POSIX

Comment: Is it necessary to free the arraylist in this function. if so., please tell me how to clear that string array.

Comment: You probably don't want to free it *in* that function, because you are returning it as a result. Usually in this case, you pass off ownership to the caller, and it becomes the caller's responsibility to properly clean up after it. You probably also want to have some way for the caller to know she's hit the last string, like by setting the last index to NULL. You could provide a utility function for freeing it to make the caller's job easier.